# how can I assure the sql select result match some value

Tags: sql

I am writing sql to select from payment table on July to December. However , I want to find out the student who has paid in all the six months. If the student has paid in all six months, then the student will be select out. If the student does not paid for any one month. Then the student will not be selected out. But I have no idea how to do it. Is it something like

select student_name from payment where (select month(payment_date) from payment) all in (7,8,9,10,11,12)

forgive me for the unclear sql. But I just want to present the idea what I want to to.

Thanks.

Comment: Which sql are you using? MySQL? Postgres? Oracle? Sqlite? Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

```
select student_name, count(distinct month(payment_date)) 
from payment 
group by student_name;
```

will show you the months that students have paid.

```
select student_name, count(distinct month(payment_date)) 
from payment 
group by student_name 
having count(distinct month(payment_date)) <> 6;
```

will show you the students that have not paid for all six months.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with the `HAVING` clause. This example specifies the months you're interested in as part of the `WHERE` clause, and then uses `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to make sure all of the months matched.

```
SELECT student_name 
  FROM payment
 WHERE month(payment_date) IN (7,8,9,10,11,12)
 GROUP BY student_name
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT month(payment_date)) = 6
```

The exact syntax will vary depending on your sql implementation.